# Issue in dynamic nodes creatinion using java(RDBMS-Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j

Below code im using for generating the multiple node dynamically. My oracle query is returning 12 rows(Table names). But i am able to create only one node here. not able to created 12 nodes. Pl help.

```
public class Connect {
    static GraphDatabaseService db;
    public static void main(String[] args)    throws SQLException
    {
        db= new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("D:\\Neo_Database\\DB10" );
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
        Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "hr", "hr");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select distinct segment_name table_name,segment_type from user_extents where segment_type='TABLE'");
        String table="";
        String segment="";
        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        while (rset.next()) {       
            table=rset.getString("table_name");        
            segment=rset.getString("segment_type");         
            Node datanode = db.createNode();
            datanode.setProperty("Schema", "HR");           
            createAndConnectNode( table, datanode,RelTypes.KNOWS );                
            tx.success();
        } 
        tx.finish(); 
    }  

    private static Node createAndConnectNode( String name, Node otherNode,
            RelationshipType relatiohshipType )
    {
        Node node = db.createNode();
        node.setProperty( name, name );
        node.createRelationshipTo( otherNode, relatiohshipType );
        System.out.println("name--------->"+name); 
        return node;
    }

    public static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you checking how many nodes are created?
It looks to me, if you have 12 items in your result set you should get 24 nodes, related in pairs.

Comment: call the tx.success() after the loop